# How dowload image from url to this custom ImageField(JsonField) Django

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-rest-framework

I have custom model_field in Project. I upload an excel file with data where I store links to photos(of this type https://url?token).I perform excel processing using pandas, and save data to the database via the serializer. How can I open the link and get the image to write it to this field of the model.

This custom field in model_field.py

```
class PsImageModelFieldBase(JSONField):

    def __init__(self, ps_image_class, **kwargs):
        assert issubclass(ps_image_class, BasePsImage)
        self.ps_image_class = ps_image_class
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        args.append(self.ps_image_class)
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def create_object(self, kwargs):
        if kwargs is None:
            return None

        try:
            if isinstance(kwargs, BasePsImage):
                return kwargs

            return self.ps_image_class(**kwargs)

        except TypeError:
            return kwargs


class PsImageModelField(PsImageModelFieldBase):

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is not None and isinstance(value, (dict, list, BasePsImage)):
            value = self.create_object(value).as_json
        return super().get_prep_value(value)

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        return self.create_object(value)
```

image.py

```
import os
import re

from django.conf import settings

from common.utils import camel_to_snake
from photoservice.service import PhotoService


class InvalidFormatError(Exception):
    pass


_default_photo_service = PhotoService()


def _validate_format(format_, format_regexes):
    is_valid = any(regex.match(format_) for regex in format_regexes)
    return is_valid


def _validate_versions(class_name, versions, format_regexes):
    for fname, format_ in versions.items():
        if not _validate_format(format_, format_regexes):
            raise InvalidFormatError(f'{class_name}: version="{fname}": "{format_}" is invalid')


class PsImageMeta(type):
    """
    Metaclass for default formats validation.
    """

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        format_regexes = attrs.get('_format_regexes') or next(b._format_regexes for b in bases)
        _validate_versions(name, attrs['default_versions'], format_regexes)
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)


class BasePsImage(metaclass=PsImageMeta):

    _default_photo_service = _default_photo_service

    _format_regexes = (
        re.compile(r'^fit_s[^0]\d{,5}x[^0]\d{,5}q\d{1,2}.jpg$'),
        re.compile(r'^(?:min|max)_s[^0]\d{,5}q\d{1,2}.jpg$'),
        re.compile(r'^same_q\d{1,2}.jpg$'),
    )

    default_versions = {}
    include_original_link = False
    new_key_template = None
    key_prefix = None

    _min_width = 100
    _min_height = 100

    def __init__(self, key, versions=None, webhook=None, redirect=None, replace=None,
                 extra_data=None, service=None, **kwargs):
        assert isinstance(key, str)
        assert versions is None or isinstance(versions, dict)
        assert self.new_key_template is not None, 'new key template must be set'

        if versions:
            self._validate_versions(versions)

        self._key = key
        self._versions = versions or self.default_versions
        self._service = service or self._default_photo_service
        self._webhook = webhook
        self._redirect = redirect
        self._replace = replace
        self._extra_data = extra_data

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(key={self._key!r})'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    @classmethod
    def new_key(cls, obj):
        return os.path.join(
            cls.get_key_prefix(),
            cls.new_key_template.format(
                class_name=obj.__class__.__name__,
                obj_id=obj.id,
            )
        )

    @classmethod
    def get_key_prefix(cls):
        return cls.key_prefix or camel_to_snake(cls.__name___)

    @classmethod
    def get_extra_data(cls, obj):
        return {
            'obj_id': obj.id,
            'obj_type': obj.__class__.__name__
        }

    @classmethod
    def for_object(cls, obj, **kwargs):
        return cls(key=cls.new_key(obj), extra_data=cls.get_extra_data(obj), **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def from_token(cls, token, service=None):
        service = service or cls._default_photo_service
        data = service.decode_token(token, raise_=True)
        return cls(**data)

    @property
    def key(self):
        return self._key

    @key.setter
    def key(self, value):
        self._key = value

    @property
    def versions(self):
        return self._versions

    @property
    def extra_data(self):
        return self._extra_data

    @property
    def links(self):
        links = {k: self.link_for(ver) for k, ver in self._versions.items()}
        if self.include_original_link:
            links['original'] = self.link_for('original' + settings.PHOTOSERVICE_ORIGINAL_IMG_EXT)
        return links

    @property
    def upload_link(self):
        return self._service.upload_link(
            self._key, self._versions, webhook=self._webhook, redirect=self._redirect,
            replace=self._replace, extra_data=self._extra_data, min_width=self._min_width, min_height=self._min_height
        )

    @property
    def as_json(self):
        """
        :return: JSON serializable dict which will be stored in DB
        """
        return {
            'key': self._key,
            'versions': self._versions
        }

    def link_for(self, version='original'):
        assert version in self._versions.values() or version in ('original', 'original' + settings.PHOTOSERVICE_ORIGINAL_IMG_EXT)
        return self._service.download_link(self._key, version)

    def _validate_format(self, format_):
        return _validate_format(format_, self._format_regexes)

    def _validate_versions(self, versions):
        _validate_versions(self.__class__.__name__, versions, self._format_regexes)
```

models.py

```
class BasePhoto(models.Model):
    photo = PsImageModelField(ps_image_class=image.SurveyImage)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def links(self):
        return self.photo.links

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ('order', 'id')
```